# Test if a lambda is stateless?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

How would I go about testing if a lambda is stateless, that is, if it captures anything or not?
My guess would be using overload resolution with a function pointer overload, or template specialization?

```
int a;
auto l1 = [a](){ return 1; };
auto l2 = [](){ return 2; };
// test l1 and l2, get a bool for statelessness.
```

Comment: Hint: if it is convertible to function pointer, it is stateless.

Comment: @Nawaz: Interesting. Do you have any quote from standard?

Comment: @MM.: I don't remember any quote, but if a lambda doesn't capture any variable, then it is implicitly convertible to function pointer.

Comment: @Nawaz: I find something and made an answer, would you check it?

Comment: Personally I would be interested whether it's also possible to get the size of the capture.

Comment: Personally I wonder why it would matter, and why anyone would want to single out lambdas. My poor old function objects feel neglected.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Because stateless lambda's convert to precisely one function pointer type, and calling the resulting pointer does the same? No guarantees in the general functor case.

Comment: @MSalters and yet they're indistinguishable from any other object with such a conversion.

Comment: Before blindly converting stateless lambdas to function pointers, recall that: (1) Calls to lambdas are more easily inlined than calls through function pointers. (2) The size of a stateless lambda is **likely** to be one byte whereas a function pointer is much bigger (typically 4 or 8 bytes).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per the Standard, if a lambda doesn't capture any variable, then it is implicitly convertible to function pointer.

Based on that, I came up with `is_stateless<>` meta-function which tells you whether a lambda is *stateless* or not.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename U>
struct helper : helper<T, decltype(&U::operator())>
{};

template <typename T, typename C, typename R, typename... A>
struct helper<T, R(C::*)(A...) const> 
{
    static const bool value = std::is_convertible<T, R(*)(A...)>::value;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_stateless
{
    static const bool value = helper<T,T>::value;
};
```

And here is the test code:

```
int main() 
{
    int a;
    auto l1 = [a](){ return 1; };
    auto l2 = [](){ return 2; };
    auto l3 = [&a](){ return 2; };

    std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<is_stateless<decltype(l1)>::value<< "\n";
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<is_stateless<decltype(l2)>::value<< "\n";
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<is_stateless<decltype(l3)>::value<< "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
false
true
false
```

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/4HptwM).

Comment: Can you explain `&U::operator()` - does that require the lambda call itself to take zero args?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: No. The lambda can take any arguments. `&U::operator()` takes the pointer of the member function which is defined as `R operator()(Args...)`. So do you see `operator()` there? Actually, `()` is operator, just like `+` in `operator+`. Did that help you?

Comment: @Nawaz, I get it now.  A function call operator with zero args would be `operator()()`.  The second `()` would contain the arguments, but the initial `()` is simply the name of the operator.  To many `(` and `)` can be confusing :P

Comment: Just note how there's an important test missing here: namely, `is_lambda` (consider: `struct poor_bastard { void operator()() const; operator void(*)(void*)() const; int haha_i_have_state_shut_up; };`). Also note how this will not have any chance of working with the upcoming polymorphic lambdas.

Comment: @Skeen: Why? Is this particular piece of information of general interest? (no!) Will anything be gained by putting it in the standard vs. implementing it as above on the (fairly rare) occasion that it's needed? (again, no!) I think Nawaz has done a fine job of meeting the OP's request, but I see no gain from putting something similar in the standard.

Comment: IMO a test that generates both false positives and false negatives is worthless.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I agree. But I don't think something like `is_lambda` can be implemented (`is_stateless` just assumes that you pass a lambda, i.e compiler generated functor). Also, C++11 things cannot support C++14 or C++-future; so it is not correct to demand that. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz someone mentioned adding it to the standard in the future (and polymorphic function objects without special syntax are not really new)

Comment: @Nawaz: You can support C++-future by not singling out lambdas as if they're something special. There are perfectly fine polymorphic function objects today, just manually specified - or created by something like `std::bind`.

Comment: There is no answer to post, because the whole premise of the question is flawed - ***lambdas are not special, don't do special things just for them***.

Comment: @Xeo: Are stateless function objects implicitly castable to function pointers the way lambdas are? - Because otherwise they are actually a bit special, and if function objects are implicitly castable, then the `is_stateless` solution actually applies to function objects as well.

Comment: A lambda without captures is not necessarily stateless btw, making the result of this test even more worthless than it already is. (consider: `static int where_is_your_statelessness_now = 0; void bar() { auto f = [/* look ma, no captures! */]{ return ++where_is_your_statelessness_now; }; ... }`)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: While it may not be stateless in that sense, it is in fact still bindable to a function pointer, right?

Comment: I don't think the goal of the question was to distinguish 'no-capture lambdas' from 'everything else' - I think it was 'no-capture lambdas'  from 'capture lambdas'.  I think I agree with @Xeo that we probably shouldn't care about the difference, but this is the question that was asked.

Comment: @Skeen, perhaps you should change 'stateless' to 'no-capture' in your question?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I worked on a *specific* meaning of stateless-ness. The first line of question says, *"How would I go about testing if a lambda is stateless, **that is, if it captures anything or not**? "*. Did you ignore that?

Comment: @Nawaz No. I'm merely stating that that meaning is a wild goose.

Comment: I only posted one comment to state that. All the others state something else. (IOW there are so many things wrong with this "problem")

Comment: Just because a lambda is stateless, does not mean it has a conversion to pointer to function - consider   auto L = []() { return [=] { return 1; }; }; auto stateless = L();  But stateless will not have a conversion to fptr.  Only lambdas that do not have any explicit, default or init-captures can have conversion to fptr.

Comment: Yeah it's more like "if a lambda _cannot_ capture a variable", rather than "doesn't".

Comment: How about `sizeof`? It may not be standard, but the stateless lambdas above seem to have a size of 1 on GCC.

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <type_traits> // std::true_type, std::false_type
#include <utility>     // std::declval

template<typename Lambda>
auto is_captureless_lambda_tester(int)
-> decltype( +std::declval<Lambda>(), void(), std::true_type {} );

template<typename Lambda>
auto is_captureless_lambda_tester(long)
-> std::false_type;

template<typename Lambda>
using is_captureless_lambda = decltype( is_captureless_lambda_tester<Lambda>(0) );
```

Does not work for polymorphic lambdas, require as a precondition that the argument be a closure type. (E.g. `is_captureless_lambda<int>` is `std::true_type`.)

Answer (score 6):

Per § 5.1.2/6

> The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function with C ++ language linkage (7.5) having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s function call operator. The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator. For a generic lambda with no lambda-capture, the closure type has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function template to pointer to function.

If it's convertible to a pointer to function, then ***MAYBE*** it has to not capture anything (stateless). In action:

```
int v = 1;
auto lambda1 = [ ]()->void {};
auto lambda2 = [v]()->void {};

using ftype = void(*)();

ftype x = lambda1; // OK
ftype y = lambda2; // Error
```

You can also use [`std::is_convertible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible):

```
static_assert(is_convertible<decltype(lambda1), ftype>::value, "no capture");
static_assert(is_convertible<decltype(lambda2), ftype>::value, "by capture");
```

Comment: Maybe mention using `std::is_convertible` to actually perform the check.

Comment: Does the standard require that capturing lambdas must *not* convert to function pointers?  Perhaps a capturing lambda could convert to a function pointer that takes an extra pointer (like 'this') that points to the state of the object?

Comment: @MM.: Note that your solution is not generic. You're assuming the signature of the function pointer. If the signature doesn't match, it doesn't necessarily mean lambda is not stateless, it could as well mean that you've used the wrong signature to begin with.

Comment: Also just because a lambda does not capture anything, does not mean it has a conversion to function pointer. If you write a default-capture and even if the lambda does not actually capture anything - it will not have a conversion-to-fptr.

Answer (score 0):

Boost.TypeTraits `is_stateless` *seems* to do the job for whatever reason without much drama:

```
#include<boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include<cassert>
int main(){
  auto l1 = [a](){ return 1; };
  auto l2 = [](){ return 2; };
  auto l3 = [&a](){ return 2; };

  assert( boost::is_stateless<decltype(l1)>::value == false );
  assert( boost::is_stateless<decltype(l2)>::value == true );
  assert( boost::is_stateless<decltype(l3)>::value == false );
}
```

`boost::is_stateless` is simple the combination of other conditions, it can be expressed in terms of standard type traits I suppose:

```
::boost::is_stateless = 
::boost::has_trivial_constructor<T>::value
&& ::boost::has_trivial_copy<T>::value
&& ::boost::has_trivial_destructor<T>::value
&& ::boost::is_class<T>::value
&& ::boost::is_empty<T>::value
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_stateless.html

Check my other answer based on `sizeof`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34873353/225186

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to explicitly look a the size of the type, a stateless should in principle have the same size as other stateless types (I picked `std::true_type` for a reference type).

```
#include<cassert>
#include<type_traits>

template<class T>
struct is_stateless_lambda : std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof(T) == sizeof(std::true_type)>{};

int main(){

  auto l1 = [a](){ return 1; };
  auto l2 = [](){ return 2; };
  auto l3 = [&a](){ return 2; };

  assert( boost::is_stateless_lambda<decltype(l1)>::value == false );
  assert( boost::is_stateless_lambda<decltype(l2)>::value == true );
  assert( boost::is_stateless_lambda<decltype(l3)>::value == false );
}
```

I don't know how portable this solution is. In any case check my other solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34873139/225186